# Backup database when no more disk space

Tags: openshift

I am trying to add an index to my mysql database. But it fails due to the disk quota error.
And now my mysql database just use up all 1gb storage because of the failure and I am not sure how can I go back...

So, I decide to backup using mysqldump or rhc backup command and then recreate the database. But they both fail because they need extra spaces...

I am get stucked now and what should I do? Can I request temporarily increase my disk quota to backup the database? Or any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `rhc app tidy <appname>` to clear up some space. Then you can go forward with your changes.

Comment: I am sorry, I already try this. But this is not the solution as the database file really uses up all space

Comment: Then I would suggest either adding more diskspace to your gear (which is super cheap) as it seems your application. Or, you could use the `rhc snapshot` to create a snapshot of your application & DB on your local machine, make your changes and reduce some of the size, then restore it back using the same `rhc snapshot` command.